# When a Row is added to Kendo grid how to set the dirty flags for that newly added rows manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Click [here](http://jsbin.com/muhaxuma/1/edit?html,output)! for the example.
 All i want is to add a new row and set the dirty flags for the newly added row's as true manually and if possible please tell me which event we should use to capture the newly added row.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the dirty indicator (the red triangle) is not possible because it is lost after each rebinding of the Grid.

If you want to get notified when new item is created you can use the edit event of the Grid and check if the model is a new one

e.g.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
     if (e.model.isNew()){
           /....
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your immediate response. even when i am trying to edit the text also e.model.isNew() shows true.when new Row is added to the grid  i want to capture that event.